# How i find out installation path on Cakephp 3

Tags: ajax, cakephp-3.x, installation-path

I have a Cakephp installation on a local wamp in:

```
c:\wwww\appname
```

and I have a countdown script in a view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(<?= $nextclaimtime * 1000;?>);
    $("#countdown").countdown({until: austDay, format: 'HMS', expiryUrl: "/users/add"});
});
</script>
```

If i specify /users/add in the expiryUrl everything works in live enviroment but in my local environment it doesn't work because the app is installed under appname.

What is the correct way to change the code so the Ajax call works in both encironments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be to use the router to generate the URL, which would create a URL with respect to the base path/URL.

```php
<?php $url = \Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add']); ?>

var expiryUrl = <?= json_encode($url) ?>;
$("#countdown").countdown({until: austDay, format: 'HMS', expiryUrl: expiryUrl});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Generating URLS](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls)**

Comment: Strange, If i use: \Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add']) it generates "\/ckfaucet\", if I use \Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'add']) it generates var expiryurl = "\/ckfaucet\/user\/add"  (but its wrong, i need /ckfaucet/users/add... maybe i did something wrong when baking?

Comment: I accepted your answer, I had a router rule like this: $routes -> connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add']); Thank you!